# Shipping Address for new Customers return blank on payment step checkout

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, onepage-checkout, billing, shipping-address

On payment step default checkout I am trying to get the customer shipping address. But sometimes returns empty (please see the image below).

[image]

I am using a code similar to this to get the Shipping Address:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
print $address->getPostcode();
```

Anyone know why this happens? 
Thank in advance

Comment: I tried to getBillingAddress... occurs some error.

Comment: I think the problem is in trying to get the address on the payment step, and it has not been saved yet. I'm editing the controllers but I'm not succeeding...

Comment: When I conclude the purchase order in the admin panel the address details appear correctly...

Comment: I came to the conclusion that it is not it too, if I reload the page before completing the purchase, and fill again address and shipping information, all data appears.

Comment: Log files are empty...

Answer (score 1):

If this is part of the one page checkout and you are working in a controller that extends `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController`, as the comments suggest what you should be able to do to get the shipping or billing information is call:

```
$this->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();
$this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
```

Another way of doing this could be to use the `getAddressAction` if you already know the address id then it might be worth considering this as this will return the address in json form:

```
/**
 * Address JSON
 */
public function getAddressAction()
{
    if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
        return;
    }
    $addressId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('address', false);
    if ($addressId) {
        $address = $this->getOnepage()->getAddress($addressId);

        if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId() == $address->getCustomerId()) {
            $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-json');
            $this->getResponse()->setBody($address->toJson());
        } else {
            $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','403 Forbidden');
        }
    }
}
```